# Read 10 numbers and display them without duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm to create a program that accepts 10 numbers from user input and displays each number only once. For example, if the user enters the numbers: 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 the code will display the number 3 only one time even though the user typed it twice.

After searching through my textbook and through forums on this site with similar questions, I'm having trouble with an error that it `cannot find the symbol i`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayWith10Numbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] myArray = new int[10];

        System.out.print("Enter " + myArray.length + " values: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++); {
            myArray[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        for(int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
        {
            System.out.print("myArray["+ (n+1) +"] is : "+ myArray[n]);
        }
    }
}
```

Please also let me know if there are any other issues with my code. I'm a beginner, but trying my best to learn and improve. Thank you.

Comment: Well considering you are doing nothing to check if you have already printed it out... I think you are asking for your work to be done. But on the other hand this is an amazing start and Your input looks good and yes that is how you would print out the array.  Also instead of `n < 10` and `i < 10` lets try doing  `i < myArray.length` and `n < myArray.length` so you don't have to change those values when you want more numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is semicolon at the end of for statement. Please remove it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++);
```

Here is the fixed program

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayWith10Numbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] myArray = new int[10];

        System.out.print("Enter " + myArray.length + " values: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            myArray[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if (!set.contains(myArray[i])) {
                System.out.println("myArray[" + i + "] is: " + myArray[i]);
                set.add(myArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's another program that does not store the input into array.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayWith10Numbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int TOTAL_NUMBERS = 10;
        System.out.print("Enter " + TOTAL_NUMBERS + " values: ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_NUMBERS; i++) {
            set.add(input.nextInt());
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();     
        for (int n : set) {
            sb.append(n).append(' ');
        }

        System.out.println("Numbers without duplicates: " + sb);
    }
}
```

The numbers will be printed in ascending order. Please replace `TreeSet` with `LinkedHashSet` as in dumb_terminal's answer if you want to display numbers in the same order as of input.

Comment: This does not deal with duplicates at all

Comment: @ScaryWombat. Thanks for the input. I have fixed the program.

Comment: why bother with the array at all?

Comment: I tried to keep the program same as in question. Anyway, add another version that copies input integers directly into set. TreeSet is used to display numbers in ascending order.

Comment: well done - exactly the same answer as http://stackoverflow.com/a/39715838/2310289, but without addressing the insertion or sort order

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot! If I may, your first code is the one I used to improve my code. What does ` Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();` do?

Comment: @JaneDone, `Set<Integer> set` declares a variable with name `set` of type `Set<Integer>` i.e. an interface for collection of `Integer`s that does not allow duplicates. `new HashSet<Integer>` creates an object of type `HashSet<Integer>` i.e. an implementation of `Set` that uses hashing algorithm to implement `Set`'s methods. There are a lot of concepts to understand the semantics of the code. Please find information about creating objects, interfaces, and generics here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinkedHashSet` to eliminate the duplicates.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        LinkedHashSet<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
            set.add(input.nextInt());
        }

        Iterator<Integer> ii = set.iterator();
        while(ii.hasNext())
            System.out.println(ii.next());
    }
```

Comment: why are you using `LinkedHashSet` vs `HashSet` ?

Comment: to preserve insertion order (i assumed it would be important)

Comment: That's what I thought too, but probably it should be sorted anyway

Answer (score 0):

Replace your for loop with

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        myArray[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: This does not deal with duplicates at all

Comment: @ScaryWombat OP did not ask about duplicates, he merely stated that this was his intention, but he asked specifically about the error he got. This answer is fine.

Comment: @Sentry The title says `Read 10 numbers and display them without duplicates`

Comment: @Sentry `let me know if there are any other issues with my code`

Answer (score 0):

There is a ';' at the end of your "for" statement, then the "for" statement has empty body, the following code has no relationship with the "for" statment.

```
{
  myArray[i] = input.nextInt();
}
```

The correct code is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   myArray[i] = input.nextInt();
}
```

You can use some Java IDE like IntelliJ IDEA, which will help you check your code and give a hint.

For example:

[image]

This will help to solve the similar problems in the future.

Comment: This does not deal with duplicates at all

Comment: @ScaryWombat OP did not ask about duplicates, he merely stated that this was his intention, but he asked specifically about the error he got. This answer is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the semicolon in the first for loop to fix the **cannot find the symbol i** issue and **use set** to remove the duplicates as shown below

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class ArrayWith10Numbers {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                Integer[] myArray = new Integer[10];

                System.out.print("Enter " + myArray.length + " values: ");

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    myArray[i] = input.nextInt();
                }

                Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
                set.addAll(Arrays.asList(myArray));

                System.out.println("Without duplicates");

                for (Integer val : set)
                    System.out.println(val);

            }
}
```

Comment: why use an array at all?

Comment: Its just an another approach. Now tell me with that approach how I can see what is entered - with duplicates?

Comment: `Its just an another approach.` - no it is bad programming